# Send button from c# to client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a helper created as follows:-

```
public static MvcHtmlString FileDomElement(this HtmlHelper helper, FileUpload fileUpload)
{
    string strOutput = string.Empty;

    if (fileUpload.MultipleFile)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileUpload.MimeType))
        {
            strOutput = "<input type=\"file\" multiple=\"multiple\" id=\"chooseFiles\" value=\"Choose File(s)\" onchange=\"ehDisplayFileNames();\" style=\"opacity: 0\" >";
        }
        else
        {
            strOutput = "<input type=\"file\" multiple=\"multiple\" id=\"chooseFiles\" value=\"Choose File(s)\" accept=\"" + fileUpload.MimeType + "\" onchange=\"ehDisplayFileNames();\" style=\"opacity: 0;\">";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileUpload.MimeType))
        {
            strOutput = "<input type=\"file\" id=\"chooseFiles\" value=\"Choose File(s)\" onchange=\"ehDisplayFileNames();\" style=\"opacity: 0;\">";
        }
        else
        {
            strOutput = "<input type=\"file\" id=\"chooseFiles\" value=\"Choose File(s)\" accept=\"" + fileUpload.MimeType + "\" onchange=\"ehDisplayFileNames();\" style=\"opacity: 0;\">";
        }
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(strOutput);
}
```

Now in the onchange event of the file I want to send the button to the backend. Because I have multiple file input elements on a single page. So I want to detect which one was clicked.

Please help me with this.

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking or what you're trying to accomplish.  "Which one was clicked" doesn't seem relevant, the posted form values (including file(s)) are really what's being sent to the server.  The posted files should correspond to the form element names, that would tell you which one was used.  (It looks like your `file` inputs don't have names, they should.)  If you're trying to send this information to the server on a client-side event then you're going to need to write client-side code to perform an AJAX request to another server-side resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try catching the event info and using that to get a reference to the sender:

```
function ehDisplayFileNames(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id + ' has fired the event!');
}
```

Your markup would need to send the event:
    onchange="ehDisplayFileNames(event);"

Mark's comment above is very true, once you have a client side id you will still need some type of Ajax call to get this info back to the server.